# What compiler flags should I use for my libraries and apps to get the best performance NDK (CMake)

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

My lib and my app use NDK(CMake).

So, question is - is there any advice how should be configure `CMake` file to get the best performance?

For example if you need to get some advice how to configure `.gitignore` file you can visit this github page

https://github.com/github/gitignore

there is a lot of examples and you can choose what you need. Is there something similar for NDK(CMake)?

Comment: Can you best more specific as to what you mean by *best performance*? In general, Stackoverflow is not the place for *general advice* or *best-practices examples*, as these types of questions lead to opinionated answers. If you have a *specific* question about a **particular** piece of code, please add this to your question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake has absorbed tons heuristics to deliver best possible performance when you simply choose a release build. It's not easy to outsmart it even if you have intimate knowledge of what your code is doing.

Still, extensive profiling and fine tuning can be fruitful. Keep in mind that different devices may not behave the same way: their CPU may throttle down because it becomes too hot, or your thread may find itself on a slower core…

If you can afford to optimise for one device, your chances are better.